# tag with element(without tag) and attribute in android using simple xml

Tags: android, simple-framework

I want to create xml string like below and for that I am using [Simple Xml](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/examples/examples.php)

```
<data name = "your name">please enter your name</data>
```

for that I am creating class

```
@Root(name = "data")
public class Data {

    @Attribute(name = "name")
    private String x;

    private String value;

    public String getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(String x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }


}
```

but it give me string after serialize like::

```
<data name = "your name"/>
```

If I set @Element annotation to value

```
 @Element
 private String value;
```

then it is comes with value tag that I dont want

```
<data name = "your name"><value>please enter your name</value></data>
```

so how can I map above string from object?

What If I have `<font color = "red">this is text</font>` . How can I handle it?

Comment: can you please explain for -1 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use @Text attribute.

Example :

```
@Root
public class Entry {

   @Attribute
   private String name;

   @Attribute
   private int version;     

   @Text
   private String value;

   public int getVersion() {
      return version;           
   }

   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }

   public String getValue() {
      return value;              
   }
}
```

Output:

```
<entry version='1' name='name'>
   Some example text within an element
</entry>
```